# Can I do Android Development in Ubuntu without Eclipse?

Tags: android

I encountered some issues getting started with Android Development on Ubuntu. Installing the JDK was painful, and the Eclipse GUI is not that intuitive. Despite these setbacks I'm still interested and would like to know what other tools are available to me when working with android.

What tools in the Android SDK keep me locked into eclipse? Is there a way to run these tools without using the GUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can totally code Android apps in your favourite text editor and [build them from command line](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html), but, seriously, don't expect it to be less confusing then coding in Eclipse.

Comment: Isn't NetBeans a viable alternative?

Comment: All Android howtos and tutorials are for Eclipse. It is possible to use Netbeans or, as I said, a plain text editor but it certainly would require more effort to set up and configure. Also, I'm not sure about Netbeans' level of integration with the SDK - in Eclipse there are wizards, form editors, remote debugging and other stuff - I'm not sure if Netbeans provides anything beyond text editing

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html), which is currently in Beta.

You can install Android Studio next to Eclipse on Ubuntu, I develop some older projects in Eclipse and newer ones in Android Studio. Running both at the same time will confuse `adb`.